# I want to add color to header using css in navbar react bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

This is my css

```
.h1, h1{
    font-size:2.5 rem;
    font-style:italic;
    color : wheat
 }
```

I have also tried page header in navbar form when I refresh the page colour style was not applying for the header. I have enclosed header within the nav bar.

Comment: Please post the HTML code too. what is .h1 ???

Comment: Please explain the questions properly, otherwise someone will flag the question.

Comment: I want add color to the header tag. I have written header in the navbar. When i have applied color during inspection it worked. when i have refreshed the the applied color was not visible. I have written my source code in react js

Comment: @Tarun Inspection in browser is for debugging purpose. Please add the style in the respective class used for nav.

Comment: <Navbar  inverse collapseOnSelect>
           <h1 className="h"> Disciplinary Issues Tracking </h1>
  <font size="3">
  <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav >
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/Register">
        Admin Register
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="/login">
        Admin login
      </NavItem>
      </Nav>
            </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
  </font>
</Navbar>

Comment: The above was my source code

Comment: better add this is the question itself rather than adding here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your source code:

```
    <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
       <h1 className="h"> Disciplinary Issues Tracking </h1> <font size="3"> 
        <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav > 
                <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/Register"> Admin Register </NavItem> 
                <NavItem eventKey={2} href="/login"> Admin login </NavItem> </Nav> 
            </Nav> 
        </Navbar.Collapse> 
    </font> // I don't know why it's there
    </Navbar>
```

your css should be :

```
h1.h{
    font-size:2.5 rem;
    font-style:italic;
    color : wheat;
 }
```

Comment: You are welcome, mark it as solved to close the question please.